# Selecting count of consecutives dates before and after a specified date based on start/end

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to determine the number of records with consecutive dates (previous record ends on the same date as the start date of the next record) before and after a specified date, and ignore any consecutive records as soon as there is a break in the chain.

If I have the following data:

```
-- declare vars
DECLARE @dateToCheck    date = '2020-09-20'
DECLARE @numRecsBefore  int = 0 
DECLARE @numRecsAfter   int = 0
DECLARE @tempID         int

-- temp table
CREATE TABLE #dates
    (
    [idx]       INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [startDate] DATETIME ,
    [endDate]   DATETIME,
    [prevEndDate] DATETIME
    )

-- insert temp table
INSERT INTO #dates 
        ( [startDate], [endDate] )
VALUES  ( '2020-09-01', '2020-09-04' ),
        ( '2020-09-04', '2020-09-10' ),
        ( '2020-09-10', '2020-09-16' ),
        ( '2020-09-17', '2020-09-19' ),
        ( '2020-09-19', '2020-09-20' ),
        --
        ( '2020-09-20', '2020-09-23' ),
        ( '2020-09-25', '2020-09-26' ),
        ( '2020-09-27', '2020-09-28' ),
        ( '2020-09-28', '2020-09-30' ),
        ( '2020-10-01', '2020-09-05' )

-- update with previous records endDate
DECLARE @maxRows int = (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM #dates)
DECLARE @intCount int = 0
WHILE @intCount <= @maxRows
BEGIN
    UPDATE #dates SET prevEndDate = (SELECT endDate FROM #dates WHERE idx = (@intCount - 1) ) WHERE idx=@intCount
    SET @intCount = @intCount + 1 
END

-- clear any breaks in the chain?


-- number of consecutive records before this date 
SET @numRecsBefore = (SELECT COUNT(idx) FROM #dates WHERE startDate = prevEndDate AND endDate <= @dateToCheck)

-- number of consecutive records after this date 
SET @numRecsAfter = (SELECT COUNT(idx) FROM #dates WHERE startDate = prevEndDate AND endDate >= @dateToCheck)


-- return & clean up
SELECT * FROM #dates
SELECT @numRecsBefore AS numBefore, @numRecsAfter AS numAfter
DROP TABLE #dates
```

With the specified date being '2020-09-20, I would expect @numRecsBefore = 2 and @numRecsAfter = 1. That is not what I am getting, as its counting all the consecutive records.

There has to be a better way to do this. I know the loop isn't optimal, but I couldn't get LAG() or LEAD() to work. I've spend all morning trying different methods and searching, but everything I find doesn't deal with two dates, or breaks in the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads like a gaps-and-island problem. Islands represents rows whose date ranges are adjacent, and you want to count how many records preceed of follow a current date in the same island.

You could do:

```
select 
    max(case when @dateToCheck > startdate  and @dateToCheck <= enddate then numRecsBefore end) as numRecsBefore,
    max(case when @dateToCheck >= startdate and @dateToCheck <  enddate then numRecsAfter end) as numRecsAfter
from (
    select d.*, 
        count(*) over(partition by grp order by startdate) as numRecsBefore,
        count(*) over(partition by grp order by startdate desc) as numRecsAfter
    from (
        select d.*,
            sum(case when startdate = lag_enddate then 0 else 1 end) over(order by startdate) as grp
        from (
            select d.*,
                lag(enddate) over(order by startdate) as lag_enddate
            from #dates d
        ) d
    ) d
) d
```

This uses `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()` to define the islands. The a window count gives the number and preceding and following records on the same island. The final step is conditional aggrgation; extra care needs to be taken on the inequalities to take in account various possibilites (typically, the date you search for might not always match a range bound).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=434a7efb83dbe86c564abe1395079962)**

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you are after, however, this does not give the results in your query; I suspect that is because they aren't the expected results? One of the conditional aggregated may also want to be a `>=` or `<=`, but I don't know which:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT startDate,
           endDate,
           CASE startDate WHEN LAG(endDate) OVER (ORDER BY startDate ASC) THEN 1 END AS IsSame
    FROM #dates d)
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN startDate < @dateToCheck THEN IsSame END) AS numBefore,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN startDate > @dateToCheck THEN IsSame END) AS numAfter
FROM CTE;
```